# How does git merge work when changes are made to a commit before common ancestor?

Tags: git, merge

I'm facing a peculiar scenario. It can be depicted as followes:

When I had to start development the structure of master was

1<-2<-3

I created a local branch say my_branch, and worked on it for over a month. In the process I had modified some files which were committed in commit 2.

When I had to merge, I checked out master again and did git pull origin. My master now looked like thsis

1<-2<-3<-4<5<-6<-7<-8<-9

And my_branch like this

1<-2<-3<-my_branch.1 (The last commit had modified the files committed in commit 2)

Now I checkout out master and did git merge my_branch

Should it not give conflict for the changes I made? It gives no conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it should not give any conflict, if the modified files from commit two were not modified again in the updated `master` branch.

You are only reporting the modifications you did on `my_branch` onto `master`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now, when I look at it, it makes sense, since I got the latest copy, I should be careful while modifying the existing files. Its not that I can do anything in my local branch and be sure that it will be taken care of with merge conflicts. In my case , I had commented out some stuff in original file